# Trying to access a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

```
 FlightClient.ConnectPoint_FlightClient f = new ConnectPoint_FlightClient();
        f.Open();
        CarrierCode[] code = new CarrierCode[2];
        code[0].AccessibleCarrierCode = "0M";
```

FlightClient is my reference name, when I am trying to use 'AccessibleCarrierCode' method I am getting this error.I think its because of the security, I have Security token with me but I don't know how to use it..

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   App_Web_e1jujnbd.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Comment: Update subject it is not a problem with access to web service like @Damith said below

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialize array items, default is null and it will thow exception when you access properties of null object. do as below

```
CarrierCode[] code = new CarrierCode[2];
code[0] =  new CarrierCode();
code[0].AccessibleCarrierCode = "0M";
//if you need to access code[1] then initialize it before access
```

if you have many items then

```
for(int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++) 
{
  code[i] = new CarrierCode();
}
//now you can set values of any item in the array
```

Comment: `FlightClient.ConnectPoint_FlightClient f = new ConnectPoint_FlightClient();
        f.Open();
        CarrierCode[] code = new CarrierCode[2];
        code[0] = new CarrierCode();
        code[0].AccessibleCarrierCode = "OM";
        TransactionInfo infotran = new TransactionInfo();
        infotran.CarrierCodes = code;

        RetrieveAirportRoutes rout = new RetrieveAirportRoutes();
        rout.ClientIPAddress = "192.168.10.11";
        rout.CarrierCodes = code;
        var vr = f.RetrieveAirportRoutes(rout);
        Response.Write(vr.Routes.Count());` I am getting zero why?

Comment: May be how that service implemented.  Sorry, I can't read your mind or I don't have access to your PC or don't know about the service you call.

Comment: I can send you the doc regarding this, Please help me with this. I am stuck over this so long..